# How to indent lambdas in complex assignment expressions by 4 spaces

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have an assignment expression like this (formatted by clang-format):

```cpp
auto typeParams = node->typeParams | std::views::transform([&](auto p) {
                      return m_irCtx.make(IRGenericType(p));
                  });
```

I would like to have it formatted like this:

```cpp
auto typeParams = node->typeParams | std::views::transform([&](auto p) {
    return m_irCtx.make(IRGenericType(p));
});
```

Which .clang-format option controls how lambdas are indented relative to the parent scope? How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Setting `LambdaBodyIndentation` to `OuterScope` does not change anything

Comment: When I think it improves legibility, I break out the lambda to its own variable.  `auto transform_fn = [&](auto p) { return m_irCtx.make(IRGenericType(p)); };`

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case (and if it's the only case or only one of a few) I'd just format by hand:

```cpp
// clang-format off
auto typeParams = node->typeParams | std::views::transform([&](auto p) {
    return m_irCtx.make(IRGenericType(p));
});
// clang-format on
```

Yes, that's cheating. Clang-format works reasonably well if you're happy with what it does but you cannot configure it to do anything. In these cases, you're welcome to switch the automation off and do it manually.

Looking at the code in question, I'd say that the closing brace and parenthesis should be indented by at least one level. However, what do I know. If you want it like this, write it like this and don't let clang-format touch it.